# how to give `x._1._2` parameters actual names

Tags: scala

Is there a way to name parameters `.map` function takes? See the following in Scala example:

`aggregated.map( (kv: ((String, Int, Int), (Int, Int))) =>("some stuff"))`

I would like to name them like

`aggregated.map( (kv: ((name:String, score:Int, anInt:Int), (age:Int, count:Int))) =>("some stuff"))`

This would make it easier to refer to the params when the mapping is done. For example instead of using `kv._1._2` I could say `score` or `kv.score`. Makes code more readable and easier to debug.

Comment: what you wrote is perfectly acceptable if you prepend it with a "case" a la `aggregated.map( case (name, score, anInt), (age, count)) => ...`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use "case" to extract variables from tuples using pattern matching:

```
aggregated.map { case((name, score, anInt), (age,count)) => ... }
```

you do not need to specify type annotations, the type inferencer does that for you:

```
    scala> List((("a",true,2),(1.0,2L)), (("b",false,11),(2.0,3L))).map { 
       case ((a,b,c),(d,e)) => s"$a$b$c$d$e" 
    }
    res3: List[String] = List(atrue21.02, bfalse112.03)
```

Answer (score 2):

The usual answer is to decompose with a pattern matching anonymous function, as the other answer says, but this one also just occurred to me:

```
scala> List((("a",true,2),(1.0,2L)), (("b",false,11),(2.0,3L))).map { kv =>
     | import kv._1.{_1 => s}
     | s
     | }
res1: List[String] = List(a, b)
```

That's fewer byte codes than the pattern match if you're not extracting all the fields.

```
scala> List((("a",true,2),(1.0,2L)), (("b",false,11),(2.0,3L))).map {
     | case ((s,_,_),_) => s
     | }
res2: List[String] = List(a, b)
```